# ContentView isn't Showing up Inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, programmatically-created

I'm having trouble getting my `ContentView` to show up inside my `ScrollView` and I don't know what I'm doing wrong to make it not visible. In my screenshot down below, the purple view is my `ScrollView` which is showing perfectly, and as you will see in my code, my `ContentView` is red. I tried to change my properties to `lazy var` to see if that would work, but I'm still having the same issue. Am I doing something wrong in my programmatic UI for my `ContentView` not to show up, or am I missing something? Thank you!

**Screenshot of Problem**

[image]

**FindEmployeeJobRequestController**

```
// MARK: - Properties

lazy var jobInfoCardView: ShadowCardView = {
   let view = ShadowCardView()
   view.backgroundColor = .white
   view.addShadow()
   view.setHeight(height: 320)
   return view
}()
    
let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
   let sv = UIScrollView()
   sv.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
   sv.isScrollEnabled = true
   return sv
}()
    
let contentView: UIView = {
   let view = UIView()
   view.backgroundColor = .red
   return view
}()

// MARK: - Helper Functions

fileprivate func configureUI() {

        view.addSubview(jobInfoCardView)
        jobInfoCardView.anchor(top: circularProgressView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor,
                               paddingTop: 52, paddingLeft: 24, paddingRight: 24)
        
        jobInfoCardView.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.anchor(top: jobInfoCardView.topAnchor, left: jobInfoCardView.leftAnchor,
                          bottom: jobInfoCardView.bottomAnchor, right: jobInfoCardView.rightAnchor,
                          paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 4, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 4)
        
        jobInfoCardView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.anchor(top: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leftAnchor,
                           bottom: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, right: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.rightAnchor)
        contentView.anchor(left: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, right: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.rightAnchor)

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I tried to add my `contentView` to my `scrollView`'s subview, but it's still not showing. I even tried to add an `UIStackView` to my `contentView` to see if that could make it visible, but still not visible.

**Updated Screenshot**

[image]

**Updated Code**

```
fileprivate func configureUI() {

        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.anchor(top: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leftAnchor,
                           bottom: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, right: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.rightAnchor)
        contentView.anchor(left: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, right: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.rightAnchor)
        
        waitingOnEmployeeStack.axis = .vertical
        waitingOnEmployeeStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        waitingOnEmployeeStack.spacing = 4
        
        contentView.addSubview(waitingOnEmployeeStack)
        waitingOnEmployeeStack.centerX(inView: contentView)
        waitingOnEmployeeStack.anchor(top: contentView.topAnchor, paddingTop: 5)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to add the contentView as a subView of the scrollView.

```
fileprivate func configureUI() {
    
    view.addSubview(jobInfoCardView)
    jobInfoCardView.anchor(top: circularProgressView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor,
                           paddingTop: 52, paddingLeft: 24, paddingRight: 24)
    
    jobInfoCardView.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.anchor(top: jobInfoCardView.topAnchor, left: jobInfoCardView.leftAnchor,
                      bottom: jobInfoCardView.bottomAnchor, right: jobInfoCardView.rightAnchor,
                      paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 4, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 4)
    
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.anchor(
        top: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
        left: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leftAnchor,
        bottom: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
        right: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.rightAnchor
    )
    contentView.anchor(
        left: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.leftAnchor,
        right: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.rightAnchor
    )
    
}
```

Comment: I just tried, and still isn't showing. I even tried adding labels to my `contentView` to see if that would work too. Labels show but still no `contentView`

Comment: @ZacharySmouse try to give it explicit size (height and width). Also use debug hierarchy.

Comment: You were correct, I had to set a height constraint on my `contentView` and now everything is working! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to add `contentView` as `scrollView`'s subview and not `jobInfoCardView`'s subview

Answer (score 0):

Couple notes...

I ***strongly recommend*** using standard constraint syntax - at least while you're learning. We don't know if your `.anchor(...)` funcs are doing the right thing, and when you review your code it's not entirely clear what might be happening. Once you've really gotten the hang of auto-layout, you *may* find it easier to use "helper funcs" (personally, I don't).

Also - ***use comments*** so both you and we know what your **intent** is.

Take a look at this...

You haven't shown what `ShadowCardView` might be, so we'll start with just a plain `UIView` subclass:

```
class ShadowCardView: UIView {
}
```

And an example controller class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    lazy var jobInfoCardView: ShadowCardView = {
        let view = ShadowCardView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        return view
    }()
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.backgroundColor = .purple // .darkPurpleTint
        return sv
    }()
    
    let contentView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()
    
    let circularProgressView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.6, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1.0)
    
        // we'll be using auto-layout constraints for all views
        [jobInfoCardView, scrollView, contentView, circularProgressView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        // add views
        view.addSubview(circularProgressView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        
        contentView.addSubview(jobInfoCardView)
        
        // respect safe area
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // to make things a little more readable
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // let's put the circularProgressView 20-points from the Top
            circularProgressView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            // 60-points on each side
            circularProgressView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            circularProgressView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: -60.0),
            // and give it 1:1 ratio
            circularProgressView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: circularProgressView.widthAnchor),
            
            // let's put the scrollView 20-points from the Bottom of the progress view
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: circularProgressView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            // 20-points on each side
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // and give it 1:1 ratio
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),

            // constrain all 4 sides of contentView to scrollView's Content Layout Guide
            //  and we'll use 12-points "padding" so we can see its frame inside the scrollView
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            
            // set the Width of contentView to the Width of scrollView's Frame Layout Guide
            //  mius 24-points (12 on each side)
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor, constant: -24.0),
            
            // constrain all 4 sides of jobInfoCardView to contentView
            jobInfoCardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            jobInfoCardView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            jobInfoCardView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            jobInfoCardView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

When run, it will look like this (green view is your `circularProgressView` and purple view is the scroll view):

[image]

That's pretty much what you are already getting. That's because - at the moment - `ShadowCardView` has no content to control its size. So, it's not even visible.

Let's change `ShadowCardView` to this:

```
class ShadowCardView: UIView {
    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 20
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(stackView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain all 4 sides of stackView to self
            //  and we'll use 8-points "padding" so we can see its frame
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])
        
        // give the stackView a border so we can see its frame
        stackView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        stackView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        
        // add some labels
        for i in 1...30 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.text = "Label \(i)"
            v.backgroundColor = .cyan
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
    }
}
```

We've added a vertical stack view with 30 labels (along with proper constraints), and the output is now:

[image]

and we can scroll:

[image]